# How to handle push notification payload without tapping it when the app is in not running or background state

Tags: ios, swift

I have to locally store Title and Body of all the notifications coming in my iOS app and display those in a notifications screen. I'm able to store all the notification tapped by using these-

This gets called when the app is in not running state or killed when the push notification is tapped-

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {...}
```

This gets called when app is running in foreground or background and push notification is tapped-

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {...}
```

My question is how to store notifications without tapping on notifications.
I want to store the notifications even if the notification is dimissed/cleared by user.

I know this method is called when app is active and in the foreground and push notification comes-

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {..}
```

How to handle push notification data without tapping on it when the app is in background or not running state?

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to handle notification when your app is not in a running state - at least if you don't use VOIP. I had a quite similar issue and was wrote a question here (with no success) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51055491/apple-push-notifications-apn-inconsistency

Comment: @Teetz Is there a way to handle the notifications data when the user opens the app next time?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but i don't think so. AFAIK apps that do that are storing their push notifications on their backend-server and ask the backend at app start to get all the remote notification data.

Answer (score 4):

1- If the app isn't running then no way to wake up the app only with ( VOIP )

2- if in background then add this key to the sended payload

> "content_available": true

And enable **RemoteNotifications** from app capabilities

Comment: 1- I don't want to wake up the not running app when a notification arrives. Is there a way to get the notifications data when the user opens the app next time?

2- In which method can I get the notification data when "content_available": true is there in payload?

Comment: 1 - If you have `content_available` set to 1 or true and your app is in background, then `func application(_: didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:)` will be called instantly without user action, but you have to call `completionHandler` within 30 seconds since the method was called. If you don't have `content_available` then the mentioned method is called when the user taps the alert or when the app is put to foreground.